# Restarting GAE in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

So I am learning Google App Engine with Java. When modifying files i realized I dont always see my changes. I try clicking the red button to stop the web application in eclipse and then restarting the application however I dont see the changes. This even happens if i run chrome in incognito mode. I also have the same problem with IE and Firefox (By default i use firefox when developing due to my preference of firebug).

Also at times I will get annoyed with one project and start a new google app engine project. However the GAE will still be running the first one not the second one even though i close the project. Even worse was when i deleted the root project folder I still saw the index.html page though the links were broken for the project i deleted.

I am thinking there are two issues one is that my browser is storing these files in a cache. And the other is that I am not actually restarting the google app engine. Is the right procedure just to click the red square in the console in eclipse or is there something to run on the command line (in windows)?

**To be brief , if i want to stop the GAE from in eclipse and restart it to see any changes i made whats the easiest way to do this on windows?**

Thanks

edit:

Rumor has it that adding Google Web Toolkit to the project made my App Engine launch show up in the Development Mode pane, where it could be easily be killed or restarted. Is handling this issue this way a wise idea?

[Trying out this touch command idea, i was hoping there was a command line way to restart the server similar to ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800701/how-do-i-restart-the-google-app-engine-java-server-in-eclipse?rq=1)
[the answer by dragon in this question would be helpful if it had more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210625/how-to-rebuild-and-restart-the-gae-server-for-a-project)

Comment: Could you try and be a little more clear?  Maybe put your question in bold and in ten words or less?

Comment: sure , good point sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red button will stop it.  You shouldn't need to run anything from the command line.

What you should do though is look at "Developement Mode" view and confirm nothing is running.  It's under Window-->show view -->Other--> Google.  Clicking on the gray arrows will show you what is open (running or not). Also, you can press the grey Xs to clear all stopped instances. This should confirm if something is running.

Also, look under run --> run configurations -->server.  You have an option to set the port, or have it automatically set.  If you are trying to run more than one project, your second one may not start if the first one has already taken the port.  Keep that in mind.

As far as your browser storing Dev Mode page in cache, I don't think it can.  In fact, if you close the running dev mode in instance your browser page should immediately update reflecting the fact that it has lost a connection.  If it doesn't, surely you didn't manage to shut it down.

Ok, so I said the red button will stop it and it will, but you have to get the right red button.  If you have more than one instance running, again look at the "Developement Mode" view, there is only one red button and you have to use the grey arrows I mention to get focus on the dev mode instance you want.

It's not really that complicated and you'll have it down by tommorrow![image]

Here is the Dev. Mode view.  You can see I have three instances.  The first is actually running, but shows red as there was an error. Clicking the grey grey Xs will get rid of the second two non-running instances and clicking the document icon with one grey x (it's not greyed out), will clear the log from the current running instance and remove the red x as there would then be no errors in the log.

Got it?